# Sending Text to Command Prompt when opened as Administrator

Tags: automationanywhere

I've managed to open Command Prompt "CMD" as Administrator

Issue is when i try to send keystrokes to it nothing happens

I tried opening CMD normally (not as administrator), it works okay

Any idea how can i make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Just a hunch, but are you running your script as an administrator? If you don't, it might not have permission to write to an administrator prompt

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried running as admin but no success. Very strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I think you're experiencing this do to either a malware/virus defender on your machine or a Windows UAC (User Access Control) setting. Also, try changing the elevated command prompt options [like these here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-a-look-at-windows-10s-new-command-prompt-features/) and see if changing QuickEdit Mode or Insert Mode has any effect on the automation anywhere control of the window. If it is determined to be a UAC issue, please refer to AA's suggestions on that [here](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/customizing-an-automation-client/setting-user-access-control.html).